# How to convert array of char to variable long in C?

Tags: c, long-integer, typeconverter, arrays

I have been trying for hours to convert this. I have tried looping through the array casting the chars to longs, but that wouldn't work. I have seen simple examples online, but they don't cover a looping process for longer char arrays. What is a method I could use to convert this array of char (SAMPLE) to one variable of type long?

ar.h

```
struct  ar_hdr       /* file member header */
     {
         char    ar_name[16];    /* '/' terminated file member name */
         char    ar_date[12];    /* file member date */
         char    ar_uid[6]       /* file member user identification */
         char    ar_gid[6]       /* file member group identification */
         char    ar_mode[8]      /* file member mode (octal) */
         char    ar_size[10];    /* file member size */
         char    ar_fmag[2];     /* header trailer string */
     };
```

My code

```
struct ar_hdr sample;
lseek(fileD, 24, SEEK_SET); //fileD is the file desriptor for the opened archive

//I start at 24 because of the 8 byte magic string for an archive starts the file "!<arch>\n"


int numRead = read(fileD, sample.ar_date, 12);
printf(sample.ar_date);

long epoch = (long *) *sample.ar_date;   //terrible coding here
printf("The current time is: %s\n", asctime(gmtime(&epoch)));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it the case that every four/eight bytes in the file represent a long or what?

Comment: if the characters represent a string in decimal format, use the `atol` function

Comment: why are you trying to assign epoch, a variable of long, with a pointer to long?
also, I guess ar_date is a pointer... But pointer to what? char?

Comment: Please post the definition of ar_hdr

Comment: Bytes 24 through 36 represent the Data for the header ar.h in unix. That's why I use lseek to start at 24 and only read 12 bytes. ar_date is a pointer to the variable in the ar.h struct ar_hdr

Comment: I used the following code and it worked! long epoch = atol(sample.ar_date);  Thanks a lot Yefim Dinitz!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`man ar`](http://man.cx/ar%283%29)** says :

> All information in the file member headers is in **printable ASCII**. The
>   numeric information contained in the headers is stored as decimal
>   numbers (except for ar_mode which is in octal). Thus, if the archive
>   contains printable files, the archive itself is printable.

So **`atol(ar_date)`** should do the trick.